# Paypal PLUS 'Direct Debit' does not work

Tags: php, paypal

I have the following array for paypal plus. This works great for (iframe) 'Paypal' and 'Credit Card' payments. But does not work for 'Direct Debit'.

```
[_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
    (
        [intent] => sale
        [experience_profile_id] => TXP-2UP57256T6655231G
        [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
            (
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                    (
                        [payment_method] => paypal
                    )

            )

        [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object
            (
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                    (
                        [return_url] => http://test.localhost/paypal/payment.php?success=true
                        [cancel_url] => http://test.localhost/paypal/payment.php?success=false
                    )

            )

        [transactions] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [total] => 10.50
                                                [currency] => USD
                                                [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [subtotal] => 7.50
                                                                [tax] => 1.50
                                                                [shipping] => 1.50
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [description] => Payment description
                                [invoice_number] => 5936611845485
                                [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [items] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => Ground Coffee 40 oz
                                                                        [description] => Ground Coffee 40 oz
                                                                        [price] => 7.50
                                                                        [currency] => USD
                                                                        [quantity] => 1
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [related_resources] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [id] => PAY-9X212986B0791962DLE3GCGI
        [state] => created
        [create_time] => 2017-06-06T08:00:25Z
        [links] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9X212986B0791962DLE3GCGI
                                [rel] => self
                                [method] => GET
                            )

                    )

                [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-41B117362N517473Y
                                [rel] => approval_url
                                [method] => REDIRECT
                            )

                    )

                [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9X212986B0791962DLE3GCGI/execute
                                [rel] => execute
                                [method] => POST
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Once i put all of  my dummy bank details it says: `We can not complete your purchase at the time
Please go back to the dealer and choose another payment method.`

[Here is the link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding?country=DE&useraction=continue&token=EC-41B117362N517473Y&country.x=DE&locale.x=en_EN&paymentMethod=bank#/checkout/guest) (I am testing it in sandbox):

Can any one help?